# Variables in PDE map files

Tags: eclipse, pde, map-files

Some PDE builds use map files. In my case, the project is BIRT and the map files contains things like:

```
plugin@org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.extension=r262_v20110127,:ext:xgu@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/birt,,source/org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.extension
plugin@org.apache.batik.svggen.source,1.6.0=GET,http://build-birt/software/platform/orbit-S20100519200754-Helios/bundles/org.apache.batik.svggen.source_1.6.0.v200805290154.jar,usetimestamp=true
```

The problems are ":ext:xgu" and "http://build-birt/"

I'm not xgu (I don't even have SSH access to the BIRT repo) and my DNS can't resolve "build-birt".

How can this be solved? Is there an ANT task in the PDE build where I can replace Strings in map files before Ant tries to fetch resources? Or is it possible to use variables in map files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your **customTargets.xml** file (copied from the template).  I have a `getMapFiles` target where it grabs the map files (in my case) from CVS.  You could add a line at the end of that target to fix your map files.

You might be able to use the replace task, or you may need something more sed-like.  ex replace:

```
<replace file="${buildDirectory}/pluginVersions.properties" token="HEAD" value="${timestamp}" />
```

My example is fixing one of our .properties files.